# how to restrict certain users from ticking excel checkbox

Tags: excel, checkbox, edit

is it possible to enable only a certain user to select / tick a check box in excel? this is because I want only the authoriser to tick the box once they are happy with the report to be sent out. cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your checkbox is called `CheckBox1` and the authoriser's network name is "JSMITH" then you can use:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If Environ("username") <> "JSMITH" Then
        CheckBox1.Value = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thnks. unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.. I assigned the macro to my check box and when I tick te box it keeps saying "object required". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: OK, in the properties for the checkbox, set the "Cell link" property to a spreadsheet cell that you can use to store the value of this check box. Let's say you set the Cell link to A1. Change the line of code inside the `If` block to read `Range("A1") = False`.